# Woocommerce; Hide/Show out of stock products on front-end

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm aware of the fact that we can control the visibility of out of stock products from the admin panel, but I just wonder if there's a way to let users themselves hide/show out of stock products in front-end? For example, a checkbox in the sidebar like a filter?

Regards

Comment: Is there any way I can bump this thread?